ASP.NET Web API : data object with JsonPropertyName attribute expect the payload to be the JsonPropertyName and i need the reular propertyName instead
This is the API method:
[Authorize]
[HttpPost("pa/questionnaire")]
[ProducesResponseType(200, Type = typeof(ApiResponse))]
[ProducesResponseType(500, Type = typeof(ApiResponse))]
public async Task<IActionResult> FillPA([FromBody] QuestionnaireData data)

This is the QuestionnaireData class:
public class QuestionnaireData
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? SignedDate { get; set; }
    public Questionnaire Questionnaire { get; set; }
}

public class Questionnaire
{   
    [JsonPropertyName("patient_signature_date")]
    public DateTime? PatientSignatureDate { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("patient_dob")]
    public DateTime? PatientDob { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("patient_email")]
    public string PatientEmail { get; set; }
    
    [JsonPropertyName("patient_gender")] 
    public string PatientGender { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("patient_cell_phone")]
    public string PatientCellPhone { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("patient_address")]
    public string PatientAddress { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("patient_city")]
    public string PatientCity { get; set; }
}

I need to use this payload (with original properties name):
{
    "Id": "234567",
    "signedDate": "2024-09-30T00:00:00",
    "questionnaire": {
                         "patientEmail": "september18@yopmail.com",
                         "patientCellPhone": "(817)-123-4567",
                         "patientDob": "2001-02-02",
                         "patientGender": "female",
                         "patientAddress": "96 FOREST ST",
                         "patientCity":"BOSTON"
                     }
}

But instead it only works with the json property name :
{
    "Id": "a5UU90000002VEEMA2",
    "signedDate": "2024-09-30T00:00:00",
    "Questionnaire": {
         "patient_dob": "2024-09-30T08:16:06.509Z",
         "patient_email": "string",
         "patient_gender": "string",
         "patient_cell_phone": "string",
         "patient_address": "string",
         "patient_city": "string"
    }
}

I need the attribute for future use (in order - to convert the object values to key value pairs and post it to another API), but not for the payload naming,
Does anyone have any idea?

Well, the JsonPropertName values define how the JSON looks like - so if you want to have patientCity, then you need to use [JsonPropertyName("patientCity")] for your property

I have no idea what the problem is. If the JSON that you deserialize the data from is using the "original" propertty names, then lose the JsonPropertyName atttributes. If you then need to serialize to different names then you need to use a different tool. Either map to a different type (that is annotated with those names) or use a custom naming policy when serializing.

@marc_s - i mentioned i then forward the data to another API where i need the value there, but in this API i need it as property name, is there a way to do it ?

I create a sample and make it works, here is my detailed steps.
The structure of project

Test Code
1. CaseInsensitiveConverter.cs
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class CaseInsensitiveConverter<T> : JsonConverter<T> where T : new()
    {
        public override T Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.StartObject)
                throw new JsonException();

            var instance = new T();
            var properties = typeToConvert.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.EndObject)
                    return instance;

                if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.PropertyName)
                    throw new JsonException();

                var propertyName = reader.GetString();
                var property = properties.FirstOrDefault(p =>
                    string.Equals(p.Name, propertyName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                    string.Equals(ToSnakeCase(p.Name), propertyName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

                if (property == null)
                {
                    reader.Skip();
                    continue;
                }

                reader.Read();

                var value = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(ref reader, property.PropertyType, options);
                property.SetValue(instance, value);
            }

            return instance;
        }

        public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value, options);
        }

        private string ToSnakeCase(string input)
        {
            return Regex.Replace(input, "([a-z0-9])([A-Z])", "$1_$2").ToLower();
        }
    }
}

2. Use it in model.
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class QuestionnaireData
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime? SignedDate { get; set; }
        [JsonConverter(typeof(CaseInsensitiveConverter<Questionnaire>))]
        public Questionnaire Questionnaire { get; set; }
    }

    public class Questionnaire
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("patient_signature_date")]
        public DateTime? PatientSignatureDate { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("patient_dob")]
        public DateTime? PatientDob { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("patient_email")]
        public string PatientEmail { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("patient_gender")]
        public string PatientGender { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("patient_cell_phone")]
        public string PatientCellPhone { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("patient_address")]
        public string PatientAddress { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("patient_city")]
        public string PatientCity { get; set; }
    }
}

3. Register it (Use System.Text.Json, not Newtonsoft)
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new CaseInsensitiveConverter<Questionnaire>());
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
});

4. Test Result
Use default one.

USE BELOW PAYLOAD.
{
    "Id": "234567",
    "signedDate": "2024-09-30T00:00:00",
    "questionnaire": {
                         "patientEmail": "september18@yopmail.com",
                         "patientCellPhone": "(817)-123-4567",
                         "patientDob": "2001-02-02",
                         "patientGender": "female",
                         "patientAddress": "96 FOREST ST",
                         "patientCity":"BOSTON"
                     }
}


